# How to get GAL from outlook on the web

Tags: javascript, node.js, outlook, cloud, gal

Is there any way to pull data from something like a GAL(global address list) in outlook on the web?
An example would be to be able to search for a contact and then taking their data from the server to be stored to local variables.

Only Use the [outlook.office.com] website
it going to run in node.js

Is there any other way to use create new app registrations in the Azure Management Portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use Exchange Web Services to search the GAL, as I don't think the [People REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/people-rest-operations) can search it:

FindPeople operation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj191039(v=exchg.150).aspx